# start stop python script that gets created dynamically

Tags: python, cron

I have a script(RelayControlMainGH.py) that monitors temperature sensors and controls relays. It uses a while true statement with a time.sleep() and runs forever. I also created a script(GetTableTimes.py) that reads 3 database table files and when they get modified a script(CreateRelayControlConfig.py) re-creates the script(RelayControlMainGH.py). So anytime I change those 3 tables in my database this new config file needs to be made because of the path changes or temp changes or logic used on the relays.

What would be a good way to stop the script(RelayControlMainGH.py) from running and allow some time for the new script to be re-created and start it up again.

I tried using cron without the while loop but the script (RelayControlMainGH.py) will not run. I am sure if I put it in cron with the while loop I will have to find it in the system to start and stop it.

What would be the best way to do this?

I am using a raspberry pi with rasbian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to create a demean service for my script(RelayControlMainGH.py) and start it upon bootup or it can be started anytime. Then in my script that creates the config file I added a stop and start of the demean so it can get the new config file and keep going. It works great!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you'll put the values that were read by GetTableTimes.py&CreateRelayControlConfig in a json file and always read them in the RelayControlMainGH.py

This way your cron jobs will be simple.
I'm not sure you need a while True loop anyway since your cron will run the script every * minute/hour/day...

I hope this will help you structure your solution better

Comment: When I take out the while loop, time.slep(60) and run the script in the terminal it does not do anything. Here is a part of the code that I am using.`code`while True:
   temp1 = tempRead1()
   if temp1 < 66:
      GPIO.output(17, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(17, True)
   if temp1 > 70 and GPIO.input(17):
      GPIO.output(27, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(27, True)
time.sleep(60)
`code`  This gets created dynamically and on the fly so I will look into json. What should I change the code above so it runs?